# JAVA String: ¿Diferencia entre Null y " "?

Tags: java, string

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String frase;



    String palabra = "";


    String mostrar = null;

    int i;
    int c = 0;

    frase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese al frase: ");
    frase += " ";
    for (i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++) {
        palabra = palabra + frase.charAt(i);
        if (frase.charAt(i) == ' ') { //asi se valida una cadena vacia
            if (palabra.length() - 1 > c) {
                c = palabra.length() - 1;
                mostrar = palabra.trim();
            }
            palabra = "";
        }
    }
    System.out.println("La palabra de mayor longitud es: " + mostrar);
    System.out.println("Su longitud es: " + c);

}
```

Me encontré con este código y lo que queria saber es ... ¿porqué usar el String mostrar = null y no un String mostrar=" ";? Al cambiar por " " y correr el programa no reconoce la palabra de mayor longitud, Agradecería su respuesta.

Comment: ¿Java o C#? No entiendo el por qué de las dos etiquetas.

Comment: Muestra un ejemplo en el que el código no sea equivalente. Acabo de probarlo y reconoce la palabra de mayor longitud.

Comment: Cuando haces: `String mostrar = null;` estás creando una instancia de la clase String llamada `mostrar` y le estás asignado al mismo tiempo un valor: `null` luego, más adelante, cambias ese valor por `mostrar = palabra.trim();` cuando haces eso, estás cambiando el valor anterior que era `null` por el valor de `palabra.trim()`. El que sea `null` al momento de declararla no influye en nada al momento de comparar si has cambiado su valor.

Comment: @A.Cedano `String mostrar = null` crea un atributo/propiedad/variable, pero no crea ninguna instancia.

Answer (score 7):

Las dos opciones significan cosas distintas, y deberían usarse de forma correspondiente.

- `null` significa "no hay valor"
- `""` significa "hay un valor". Que este valor sea la cadena vacía o no, no es relevante.

Ahora, depende de tu lógica lo que sea más sensato inicializar.

- Si hay un valor por defecto válido para ese atributo, sencillamente inicializas con ese valor. Ese valor dependerá de la lógica, y puede incluso ser `null`.
- Si no hay un valor por defecto válido, lo mejor es dejarlo en `null`. La razón es que si asignas una instancia especial (por ejemplo, `""` en el caso de String`), vas a estar teniendo que distinguir siempre entre si ese valor es el caso especial o no. Y si alguna vez te dejas esa comprobación, te vas a comer el error en vez de tener un`NullPointerException`<sup>1</sup>.

Por ejemplo, estos días estoy modificando un programa OS que tiene la puñetera manía de que, cuando no encuentra un elemento en la BD, devuelve un objeto "vacío" en vez de `null`. Así que tengo que hacer tal que así

```
 MiBean miBean = dao.getBean(clavePrimaria);
 if (miBean.getId() == 0) {
    throw new Exception("No hay bean con " + clavePrimaria);
 }
 hacerCosasConElBean(miBean.getId());
```

Si me olvido la comprobación, con suerte tendré un error inesperado en `hacerCosasConElBean()` y tendré que analizar el código hasta encontrar el error. Si no tengo suerte, hará algo que no tengo controlado<sup>2</sup> y no me daré cuenta hasta mucho más tarde,

Si el código devolviera `null`, haría

```
 MiBean miBean = dao.getBean(clavePrimaria);
 if (miBean == null) {
    throw new Exception("No hay bean con " + clavePrimaria);
 }
 hacerCosasConElBean(miBean.getId());
```

No es más complicado, y en caso de que me olvidara la comprobación saltaría una `NullPointerException` que me indicaría exactamente el punto y el fallo del error.

Tu ejemplo es similar. A no ser que `""` sea un valor válido, para lo único que sirve inicializar a `""` es para esconder algún posible error que haga que no se asigne un valor a la variable, y para confundir a quien lea tu código haciéndole creer que `""` es un valor válido y que no pasa nada si alguna rama de ejecución no asigna un valor a esa variable.

Así que `""` debería usarse si y solo si la inicialización de ese valor es opcional y `""` funciona como valor por defecto.

---

<sup>1</sup>La regla es "falla lo antes posible". Si tienes un error de programación, quieres que el programa falle cuando llegues al error, no introducir un comportamiente inesperado que te cause el fallo del programa mucho más tarde, lo que lo hace más difícil de depurar.

<sup>2</sup>Incluyendo el riesgo de alterar los datos de mi sistema de forma incorrecta.

Answer (score 3):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una imagen de ejemplo

1. Al declarar una variable esta es null por que no posee ningun valor
2. Si se declara una variable de tipo ejemplo string=" "; o int=0; solo estas inicializando

Answer (score 1):

Son inicializaciones perfectamente válidas.

Es más un acuerdo entre el equipo que estáis desarrollando el proyecto si se inicializa a NULL o a string.Empty.

Aquí vienen muchos factores que pueden inclinarse por una o por otra. Si es para escribir en base de datos, y no está permitido escribir NULL. Si necesitas consumir un servicio donde los parámetros no pueden pasarse como NULL.

Finalmente, aunque por lo que veo, mucha gente inicializa en string.Empty, no hay que dejar de tener en cuenta que cuando declaras una variable string, su valor por defecto es NULL, por lo que yo si puedo usar por defecto aquel inicialización me vale a no ser que sea por alguna limitación anteriormente descrita.

Pero a nivel de lógica, lo único que cambia es como se compara contra otra cadena y validaciones establecidas.

Comment: `cuando declaras una variable string, su valor por defecto es NULL`. Atributos/propiedades de objetos se inicializan por defecto a `null`, las variables locales **no se inicalizan** y el compilador da error si intentas usar un valor de una variable sin inicializar. De hecho, la razón para que los atributos sí se inicialicen por defecto es porque el compilador no puede cubrir todas las posibles ramas de ejecución, por lo que no puede determinar si en algún caso el atributo se usará sin ser inicializado antes.

Comment: @SJuan74, totalmente de acuerdo, solo hacia referencia a las entidades y gracias por completarlo.

Answer (score 0):

> JAVA String: ¿Diferencia entre null y “ ”?

- Si inicializas la variable con valor null, indica que no contiene
  ningun valor.
- Si inicializas con " ", indica que estas inicializando
  con un valor String.

En el caso que comentas, ùnicamente implica inicializaciòn, y revisando tu còdigo inicializando la variable mostrar con un valor null:

```
String mostrar = null
```

o un String " ",

```
String mostrar=" ";
```

**En este caso no debe hacer diferencia en los resultados**, ya que esta variable se sobreescribe en esta linea:

```
 mostrar = palabra.trim();
```

---

como prueba esta demo inicializando `mostrar` con un valor " "

https://ideone.com/YIiTV7

e inicializando `mostrar` con un valor null:

https://ideone.com/AEgqgS

---

#### Explicación gráfica de la diferencia de 0 vs Null vs NaN

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al usar `null` e intentar utilizar esa variable _(Sin alterar su valor)_, ¿No recibes `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Hola @NaCl en este caso solo le reasigna otro valor a la misma variable, me llama la atención que el OP comentan no funciona de manera similar.

Comment: Sí leí sobre el comentario del OP, pero, ¿No pasa eso al utilizar un `String` cuyo valor es `null`?

Comment: Su usas esa variable para obtener  alguna propiedad claro (ejemplo: if(mostrar.equals("palabra")){ ) , pero en este caso primero se le asigna valor null y posteriormente un valor tipo String, agreguè unas demo ideone.

Comment: En este caso sí hay diferencia en los resultados para ciertos valores de entrada puesto que no siempre se sobreescribe en la línea `String mostrar=" ";`, prueba con `frase = ""`. También es incorrecta la afirmación *"Si inicializas la variable con valor null, indica que no contiene ningun valor."*, la variable sí contiene un valor, el valor `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Ese programa es erróneo y la mejor explicación de por qué se ha hecho de una u otra manera es: **porque el autor se ha equivocado**.
No uses ese programa como ejemplo de cómo programar.

Podemos ver que ese programa es incorrecto si introducimos en el diálogo una cadena vacía. Esta demo lo demuestra : https://ideone.com/fKKHPs
El resultado es:

> La palabra de mayor longitud es: null
>   Su longitud es: 0

Que evidentemente es falso. La frase está vacía por lo que no tiene la palabra null.

Si inicializamos mostrar a `" "` en vez de a `null` tenemos un resultado mucho más correcto (demo : https://ideone.com/epPNud ) :

> La palabra de mayor longitud es:
>   Su longitud es: 0

Queda pues claro que no es lo mismo inicializar la variable mostrar a `null` o a `" "`.
Esa diferencia solo se va a notar si la cadena leida del diálogo está vacía o contiene solo espacios, en ese caso no se ejecuta nunca el siguiente condicional :

```
        if (palabra.length() - 1 > c) {
            c = palabra.length() - 1;
            mostrar = palabra.trim();
        }
```

Y al no ejecutarse la variable mostrar queda con el valor con que se inicializó originalmente. Por eso se nota la diferencia entre asignarle `null` o `" "`. En cualquier otro caso la variable es sobreescrita por ese condicional y no vas a notar diferencia funcionalmente en esos otros casos.

## Respecto a la diferencia entre null y " " en general.

Es fácil encotrar ideas equivocadas respecto a `null` como:

- null significa "no hay valor"
- Si inicializas la variable con valor null, indica que no contiene ningun valor.
- Al declarar una variable esta es null por que no posee ningun valor

Todas las afirmaciones anteriores son incorrectas. La [Especificación del Lenguaje Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7) nos dice qué es `null`:

> ## 3.10.7. El Literal Null
>
> El tipo null tiene un valor, la referencia null, representada por el
>   literal null, que se forma por sus caracteres ASCII.
>
> NullLiteral: null
>
> Un literal null es siempre del tipo null(§4.1).

Sobre el tipo null [la especificación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1) dice :

> ## 4.1. Las categorías de Tipos y Valores.
>
> (..parte omitida por no ser relevante..)
>
> También hay un tipo especial null, el tipo de la expresión
>   null(§3.10.7, §15.8.1), que no tiene nombre.
>
> Al no tener nombre el tipo null, es imposible declarar una variable de
>   tipo null o hacer una conversión(cast) al tipo null..
>
> La referencia null es el único posible valor de una expresión de tipo
>   null.
>
> **La referencia null siempre puede ser asignada o convertida(cast) a cualquier tipo de referencia**(§5.2, §5.3, §5.5).
>
> En la práctica, el programador puede ignorar el tipo null y
>   simplemente pretender que null es un literal especial que puede ser de
>   cualquier tipo referencia.

Énfasis mio. La parte en negrita es la respuesta a esta pregunta. `null` es un valor especial, **es un valor que se puede asignar a cualquier variable de tipo referencia.**
Por tanto todas las líneas siguientes son correctas:

```
Integer i = null;
String s = (String) null;
List<String> ls = (List<String>) null;
Object o = null;
```

`" "` sin embargo es un literal de cadena y al asignárselo a una variable con el operador `=` le estamos asignando una referencia a un objeto de tipo `String` que contiene la cadena de ese literal. Esa referencia de tipo String no se puede asignar a cualquier variable, se puede asignar solo a variables declaradas de tipo `String` o un tipo que sea superclase de `String`. En este caso solo `Object` es superclase de `String`.
Por ese motivo dos de las siguientes líneas son incorrectas :

```
Integer i = ""; //Error de compilación
String s = (String) ""; // Correcto
List<String> ls = (List<String>) ""; //Error de compilación
Object o = ""; // Correcto
```